# How to connect LDAP server with username and password?

Tags: c#, ldap

When I use `AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous` to connect to LDAP server, it`s ok:

```
var a = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com", "", "", AuthenticationTypes.Anonymous);
```

but when I want to use username and password to connect the server:

```
var a = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com", "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com", "111111");
```

it causes a "Specifying an invalid dn syntax" error:

[image]

If I use this:

```
var a = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/dc=moe,dc=com", "cn=Manager,dc=moe,dc=com", "111111", AuthenticationTypes.Encryption);
```

it causes an "The server is not operational" error:

[image]

So how can I connect to my LDAP server with username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's some of my piece of code when connecting to LDAP and authenticating the user used.

```
 private DirectoryEntry dEntry = null;
 private DirectorySearcher dSearch = null;

 //Validate User Credentials in Active Directory
 dEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ADPath, userName, password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

 dSearch = new DirectorySearcher(dEntry);
 dSearch.PageSize = 1000;
 dSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
 if (dSearch.FindOne() != null)
 {
   //success
 }
```

Comment: Thanks,but I cann't connect use AuthenticationTypes.Secure.My ldap server is openldap on windows.

Answer (score 0):

for validate  username and password use this code

```
using(PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN"))
{
    // validate the credentials
    bool isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials("myuser", "mypassword");
}
```

and for connect with username and password try this

```
DirectoryEntry directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://example.com", "username", "password");
```

Comment: Thanks,here is my code:var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "dc=maxcrc,dc=com");
            pc.ValidateCredentials("cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com", "111111");
            var a = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com", "cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com", "111111");

Comment: but it cann't work either,the error is "The server is not operational" too as above